# Marketing Cloud (Connect) Veeva

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber-key, veeva

We want to use Marketing Cloud Connect to connect SFMC with Veeva (2 way connection). Our use case is following:

1. Our consents are already coming to SFMC from our MDM that is already connected to Veeva.

   - There we create unique field per customer account. Let's call it AB field.
   - In order to enable **and track multiple emails per account** in SFMC we have created unique field that consists of that AB field + additional CD field.
2. At the same time we want to connect SFMC and Veeva.

   - We want to send Veeva activity data (such as calls, surveys etc.) to SFMC
   - We want to send outbound data (email clicks, opens etc.) from SFMC to Veeva

In our Veeva we don't have our SFMC subscriber key  which consist of previously mentioned AB and CD field that we created in order to enable multiple emails per 1 customer account in SFMC. We only have field AB that is unique on the account level in our MDM.

My question is how and can we at all leverage Marketing Cloud Connect to achieve this? Can Marketing Cloud Connect take only AB value from our Subscriber Key (AB+CD field) in order to populate account level data in Veeva?

Would you advise to accomplish this through some other middleware instead of  Marketing Cloud COnnect?

Many thanks community experts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to use MCC for sending Veeva CRM activity data to SFMC, which would automatically create corresponding DEs based off of Veeva objects. Theny you can use those for later segmentation and audience creation.

As for sending SFMC Email tracking data to Veeva, since you don't have SFMC subscriber key in Veeva, then it would be wise to consider other options. For example, consider using API calls or some middleware for sending the tracking data Veeva. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will be the taker. This is actually what we did after some time. Once again, thank you.